# Type mismatch error when assigning literal to Float

Tags: java, scala, math, floating-point, double

I explicitly specified a `float` type. This code produced an error. Why?

Currently, I am using scala v2.12.8

```
scala> val f: Float = 3.0
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(3.0)
 required: Float
       val f: Float = 3.0
```

Comment: [SLS 1.3.2 Floating Point Literals](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#floating-point-literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is fixed in Scala 3 (Dotty):

```
Starting dotty REPL...
Dotty compiler version 0.22.0-RC1 -- Copyright 2002-2020, LAMP/EPFL
scala> val x: Float = 3.14
val x: Float = 3.14

scala> Seq(3.14, 1)
val res0: Seq[Double] = List(3.14, 1.0)

scala> Seq[Float](3.14, 1)
val res1: Seq[Float] = List(3.14, 1.0)
```

It does not infer a type for a literal that would incur a lossy conversion:

```
scala> Seq(3.14f, 2147483646)
val res2: Seq[AnyVal] = List(3.14, 2147483646)

scala> Seq(3.14f, 2147483647)
val res3: Seq[Float] = List(3.14, 2147483647)
```

There is an open ticket to warn when a lossy conversion is required, but in general it works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code:

```
val f: Float = 3f
```

If you don't add `f` suffix, the variable will be treated as double.

It's the same thing, that happens in java, since `Double` and `Float` wrap over java's `double` and `float` respectively:

```
jshell> float f = 3.0
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
|  float f = 3.0;
|            ^-^

jshell> float f = 3.0f
f ==> 3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

To have a Float you have to suffix it with a `f`:

```
scala> val f: Float = 3.0f
f: Float = 3.0
```

By default a floating number is a `Double` as the exception suggests.

From [floating-point-literals](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#floating-point-literals) (provided by Mario Galic):

> Floating point literals are of type Float when followed by a floating
>   point type suffix F or f, and are of type Double otherwise.